# Counting Primitive Operations & Calculating Big-O Notation

Tags: java, algorithm, primitive, counting, operations

I've written a piece of java code that when given an array (arrayX), works out the prefix averages of that array and outputs them in another array (arrayA). I am supposed to count the primitive operations and calculate the Big-O notation (which i'm guessing is the overall number of calculations). I have included the java code and what I believe to be the number of primitive operations next to each line, but I am unsure whether I have counted them correctly. Thanks in advance and sorry for my inexperience, i'm finding this hard to grasp :)

```
double [] arrayA = new double [arrayX.length]; *(3 Operations)*

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayX.length; ++i) *(4n + 2 Operations)* 
    {
        double sum = arrayX[i]; *(3n Operations)*

        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) *(4n^2 + 2n Operations)*
        {
            sum = sum + arrayX[j]; *(5n^2 Operations)*
        }
        arrayA[i] = sum/(i+1); *(6n Operations)*
    }
    return arrayA; *(1 Operation)*
```

**Total number of operations:** 9n^2 +15n + 6

Comment: You've got the right idea, but the fundamental concept behind Big-O notation is that we're interested in the order of operations, not the literal quantity. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it) may help shed some light on the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any standard definition of "what constitutes a primitive operation".  I'm assuming this is a class assignment; if your instructor has given you detailed information about what operations to count as primitive operations, then go by that, otherwise I don't think he can fault you for any way you count them, as long as you have a reasonable explanation.

Regarding the inner loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
```

please note that the total number of times the loop executes is not *n*<sup>2</sup>, but rather 0+1+2+...+(*n*-1) = *n*(*n*-1)/2.  So your calculations are probably incorrect there.

Big-O notation is not really "the total number of calculations"; roughly speaking, it's a way of estimating how the number of calculations grows when *n* grows, by saying that the number of calculations is roughly proportional to some function of *n*.  If the number of calculations is *Kn*<sup>2</sup> for any constant *K*, we say that the number of calculations is *O(n*<sup>2</sup>*)* regardless of what the constant *K* is.  Therefore, it doesn't completely matter what you count as primitive operations.  You might get 9*n*<sup>2</sup>, someone else who counts different operations may get 7*n*<sup>2</sup> or 3*n*<sup>2</sup>, but it doesn't matter--it's all *O(n*<sup>2</sup>*)*.  And the lower-degree terms (15*n*+6) don't count at all, since they grow more slowly than the *Kn*<sup>2</sup> term.  Thus they aren't relevant to determining the appropriate big-O formula.

Comment: So would that mean the operation count for the inner for loop would be as follows: for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) *(4(n(n-1)/2) Operations)* sum = sum + arrayX[j]; *(5(n(n-1)/2) Operations)*

Comment: @Phillip I'm not sure, since I really don't know what you're counting as an operation.  I'm afraid I can't help you here.  Please do remember that if the body of the loop is performed M times, the `j < i` check will be performed M+1 times.

Comment: Ok so the loop itself will be run n(n-1)/2 and will everything inside the body of the loop, and then any operations will be added to that. I'm confused about where the /2 part has come from?

Comment: @Philip Since the inner loop stops at `j < i`, that means that when `i=0` the body of the loop executes 0 times, when `i=1` it executes 1 time, when `i=2` it executes 2 times and so on.  Therefore the total number of times it executes is 0+1+2+...+(n-1) (since n-1 is the largest value of `i`).  The formula for this sum is n(n-1)/2--that's just algebra.  Look up [Arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) if you don't know how this formula is derived.